# How to configure the configuration file for MONGOS?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am not able to cofigure the configuration file for mongos. How do i set the configurations?

Comment: Best articles for MongoDB Shrading:

https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-sharding-implementation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1) Create a separate database for the config server.

```
mkdir /data/configdb
```

Step 2) Start the mongodb instance in configuration mode. Suppose if we have a server named Server D which would be our configuration server, we would need to run the below command to configure the server as a configuration server.

```
mongod –configdb ServerD: 27019
```

Step 3) Start the mongos instance by specifying the configuration server

```
mongos –configdb ServerD: 27019
```

Step 4) From the mongo shell connect to the mongo's instance

```
mongo –host ServerD –port 27017
```

Step 5) If you have Server A and Server B which needs to be added to the cluster, issue the below commands

```
sh.addShard("ServerA:27017")
sh.addShard("ServerB:27017")
```

Step 6) Enable sharding for the database. So if we need to shard the Employeedb database, issue the below command

```
sh.enableSharding(Employeedb)
```

Step 7) Enable sharding for the collection. So if we need to shard the Employee collection, issue the below command

```
Sh.shardCollection("db.Employee" , { "Employeeid" : 1 , "EmployeeName" : 1})
```